# Angular Template Directive fails when model updates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a navigation menu using an AngularJs Directive. I'm using the superfish jQuery menu plugin.

It works fine except for 2 issues.

1. as soon as the model changes, the jQuery plugin fails.
2. To make the plugin work, I had to set a timeout in the 'link' method of the directive. Which is not an elegant solution.

Here's a jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ashraffayad/xRB9u/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});


myApp.directive('navMenu', ['$parse', '$compile', function ($parse, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', //Element
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.menuData, function (val) {
                var template = angular.element('<ul class="sf-menu"  id="parentTreeNavigation"><li ng-repeat="node in ' + attrs.menuData + '" ng-class="{active:node.active && node.active==true, \'has-dropdown\': !!node.children && node.children.length}"><a ng-href="{{node.href}}" >{{node.text}}</a><sub-navigation-tree></sub-navigation-tree></li></ul>');
                var linkFunction = $compile(template);
                linkFunction(scope);
                element.html(null).append(template);

            }, true);
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('.sf-menu').superfish();
            },1000);
        }
    }
}]);
myApp.directive('subNavigationTree', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', //Element
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.tree = scope.node;
            if (scope.tree.children && scope.tree.children.length) {
                var template = angular.element('<ul class="dropdown "><li ng-repeat="node in tree.childrehttp://jsfiddle.net/ashraffayad/TwZ25/#runn" node-id={{node.' + attrs.nodeId + '}}  ng-class="{active:node.active && node.active==true, \'has-dropdown\': !!node.children && node.children.length}"><a ng-href="{{node.href}}" ng-click="{{node.click}}" target="{{node.target}}" ng-bind-html-unsafe="node.text"></a><sub-navigation-tree tree="node"></sub-navigation-tree></li></ul>');

                var linkFunction = $compile(template);
                linkFunction(scope);
                element.replaceWith(template);
            } else {
                element.remove();
            }

        }
    }
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.changemodel = function(){
        $scope.model[0].text = "some other text";
    };
    $scope.model = [
        {"text":"someText", "href":""},
        {"text":"someText", "href":""},
        {"text":"someText", "href":"", 
         "children":[{}]
        }
    ];
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
```

and the html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">Hello, {{name}}!
     <button ng-click="changemodel()">change model</button>
<nav-menu menu-data="model"></nav-menu>

</div>
```

note: for some reason jsFiddle doesn't like it when I add children array to the model. But the example works as it does on my pc without the error on jsFiddle.

Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes jQuery and Angular don't always go well together.  The setTimeout, while not elegant is often necessary because you have two frameworks fighting over the DOM.  I'd recommend that you break away from the jQuery plug-in and use Toggle Dropdown from Angular-UI: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdownToggle

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using Angular-UI already and it's great. But I need a hierarchical drop-down menu for the main website navigation. And the Toggle Dropdown is just one level.

Comment: Understood.  If you fix your fiddle, I can probably help (check the console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I like a challenge:

http://jsfiddle.net/xRB9u/8/

Your fiddle had a bunch of problems.  From memory:

- If you're going to isolate scope with `scope: true`, then you need to grab your data from somewhere like (like $rootScope, $scope.$parent, or some service).  I changed your scope so it passes through the items your directive cares about.
- This also allows you to just simply use `menuData` in the template, instead of trying to concatenate it as an object like you were, which wouldn't have worked anyway... it was the equivalent of `for node in [object Object]`
- The same treatment is needed for subNavigationTree.  You probably could've poked around the scope like you were, but this way is a bit easier and more straightforward.
- You had a jsFiddle Url pasted right in the middle of one your directive's template.

Comment: Wow, it actually works now. I will study what you have done and learn from it. Thanks a million for your help and time.